# How to divide a fixed point number by a small float number?

Tags: c, math, fixed-point

I need to divide a set of 5U11 numbers by `6.02` and would prefer to do this without casting to float and back.

5U11 means a 16-bit unsigned number, with the 11 least significant bits representing fractional part.

How should I represent `6.02` and what would be the upper bond of the error of a single calculation?

Comment: What do you want the result to be? a fixed point number iwth a fractional part of n digits or a `float` / `double`?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt The same as the input number: 5U11.

Comment: Are these unsigned of signed numbers?

Answer (score 2):

A simple scaling by 100 will suffice.

```
uns16_t x_5U11;
uns32_t acc;
acc = x_5U11;
acc *= 100;
acc += 301; // for round to nearest rather than truncation.
acc /= 602;
```

Error bound: 1/2 LSbit in `x_5U11`.

--

If speed is most important, than performing a multiple and divide (by shifting) as suggested by @alastai is the way to go.  With proper rounding, the answer should be within +/- 1 LSBit.

If accuracy is most important than this method provides +/- 1/2 LSbit (best possible answer).

[Edit] Thanks to @Ingo Leonhardt for pointing out I had an inverted solution.

Comment: It’s also a very slow way to multiply, which is why you would never do the above in practice.  Most likely you’d write 6.02 in 5U11 (or maybe 3U13), do the multiplication into a 32 bit word and use a shift to rectify the answer.

Comment: @alastair Agree the tis slower to divide by 602 than shift.  But speed is not OP's stated goal.  The above creates a well defined most accurate answer.  Its the classic question speed vs. accuracy.

Comment: Accuracy hardly seems relevant given that this answer is just plain wrong (it’s a multiply rather than a divide).  Additionally, fixed point multiplication is quite easy to characterise (and if you wanted to do round to nearest, you could just add `0x8000` after the multiplication).

Comment: @alastai This answer is correct.  Provide example that failed to back-up your assertion.  Op asked "what would be the upper bond of the error of a single calculation"?  Thus accuracy is relevant to the OP.  By dividing, the error is held to with in 1/2 LSBit - the best possible answer.  Multiplying by `(2^18 / 6.02)` and then shifting (with or without a rounding factor) does not always provide the best answer.  Try 3.0 or 0x1800 in OP's 5U11.  My answer provides 0x03FD (0.49853...).  Your method provides 0x3FC (0.49804...) and 3/6.02 is 0.49833...

Comment: My apologies — I hadn’t spotted that you’d updated the text in the answer to divide instead of multiply.  Also, your example of *my* method is incorrect; if you’re shifting by 18 bits rather than 16 bits, you should add 0x20000, not 0x8000, and in that case “my” method provides 0x03fd also.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward approach to this problem is to calculate the inverse of 6.02 as a 16 bit quantity; i.e. compute round(2^16 / 6.02) = 0x2a86.  Note that the top bit is not set, so we can choose a higher dividend and recompute for better accuracy; in this case, round(2^18 / 6.02) = 0xaa1a.

Now, take your 5U11 number and do a 16x16 to 32-bit widening multiply, then shift right by (in this case) 18 bits to get your result, as a 5U11 value.

For example:

```
14.3562 * (2^18 / 6.02) = 625148.122 / 2^18 = 2.384
0x72d9  * 0xaa1a        = 0x4c4fc40a >> 18  = 0x1313
```

You do lose a little accuracy doing things this way, and it’s possible to improve slightly on this naïve method (see the book *Hacker’s Delight* by Henry S. Warren for quite a bit more on this topic and other useful things).

Plainly if you have a machine that is capable of doing wider multiplications, you can increase the size of the dividend further than 2^18, which will increase your accuracy.

---

### Updates

#### Rounding

If you want to round to nearest, you should add *d* / 2 where *d* is your dividend (so in the example above, the dividend is 2^18, hence the rounding value is 2^17 or `0x20000`.

#### Error analysis

Given the small domain, it’s simplest to do an exhaustive search to establish the maximum error.  With the example above *and using round-to-nearest by adding `0x20000`*, the maximum error turns out to be at *x* = `0xfa19`:

```
0xfa19 * 0xaa1a + 0x20000 = 0xa62e008a >> 18 = 0x298c
```

The actual answer should be

```
31.2622 / 6.02 = 5.193058
```

while the answer we have is

```
0x298c * 2^-11 = 5.193359
```

The error in this instance is 0.000302, or 0.62 of an LSB.

#### Improving on these results

It’s possible to choose a more specific rounding constant to minimise the error bound; essentially this lets us compensate for the fact that our multiplicative inverse (here `0xaa1a`) is not precise.  In this particular instance, the best value seems to be around `0x1c200`, which yields an error bound of 0.56 of an LSB.

Comment: With a round of 0x8000 and 32-bit multiply, the largest error occurs at x = 31.158203125 (0xF944) with a result of 5.17529296875 (0x2967) which mathematically should be 5.17578125 (0x2968) or 1.0 bits off.

Comment: @chux That’s because you should have added 0x20000, not 0x8000 (because the shift chosen here is 18 bits, not 16 bits). So, actually, you get (0xf944 * 0xaa19 + 0x20000) >> 18 = 0x2968.

Comment: I also tried `0x20000` (which does make more sense) and had an answer that was even more than 1.0 bits off, (about 1.2). will post later.

Comment: @chux Unless I'm mistaken, you're out by a factor of 2.  Maximum error using the rounding value 0x20000 is 0.63 of an LSB (at 0xff6b = 31.9272).  Still not perfect (I did note that you lose a little accuracy doing things this way), but less than 1 LSB.

Comment: Using `f(unsigned x) { x *= 0xaa19; x += 0x2000; x >>= 18; return x;}` I too came up with 0xff6b = 31.9272 and a error of e:0.63.  But at ffa4 = 31.955078, I came up with `e:1.096`.  Perhaps I am not implementing you function correctly.  Curiously, when I used 0x8000, the worst case was e 1.0 as previously noted.

Comment: @chux Did you miss a zero there?  Should be `x += 0x20000;`, not `x += 0x2000`.

Comment: I think I see why its > 1.0.  Your scaling factor 43545.514... is truncated to  0xaa19 rather than rounded to  0xaa1a.  By using this and a round factor of 0x2000, the worst e:0.97 bits at x=0x03c3 0.470215

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48449/discussion-between-chux-and-alastair)

Comment: Added thought on offset calc: The difference between the multiplier used 0.166114807  (0xAA1A/2^18) and the correct multiplier 0.166112957 (1/6.02) imparts a linear bias at x=0 of 0 and at 65535 a bias of (mu - cm)*range or 0.1212 or (< 1/2 * 1/4).  By adjusting the 0x20000 offset, this bias is split in 2.  So now near 0, the bias is -0.0606 and near 65535, its +0.0606.  Thus we should expect a worst case error at _about_ 0.5606 bits.  The _approximate offset_ derives directly from 0.1212 = (0x20000 * (1 - 0.1212)).  Have yet to derive _best offset_ except by experimentation.